# How to deallocate a int*** in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

How do I deallocate this type of 3D array in c++? I have a class that has a int*** volume as a member and I filled it this way..

```
    volume = new int**[xSize];
    for(int i =0; i<xSize; i++)
    {
        volume[i] = new int*[ySize];
        for(int j =0; j<ySize; j++)
        {
            volume[i][j] = new int[zSize];
            for(int k = 0; k<zSize;k++)
            {
                volume[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same way as you allocated it, for loop and `delete` each `new` you made.

Comment: @Als: `delete[]` each `new[]`

Comment: @Benoit: Ah, Ofcourse, `delete` for each `new`, `delete[]` for each `new[]`

Comment: I really must recommend vector<vector<vector<int>>>.  Or a wrapper class for a int*, like boost::multi_array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just reverse your actions (other than the filling of the array)

```
for(int i =0; i<xSize; i++)
{
    for(int j =0; j<ySize; j++)
    {
        delete[] volume[i][j];
    }
    delete[] volume[i];
}
delete[] volume;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can, avoid manual dynamic memory management in the first place. E.g. using `std::vector`:

```
typedef std::vector<int> Vec1D;
typedef std::vector<Vec1D> Vec2D;
typedef std::vector<Vec2D> Vec3D;

Vec3D volume(xSize, Vec2D(ySize, Vec1D(zSize, 0)));
```

As pointed out in the comments, [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array) is a convenient alternative.

Comment: I am not looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recursively iterate through all levels of the structure the same way as above (except the innermost level), and `delete` each element in reverse order compared to their allocation:

```
for(int i =0; i<xSize; i++)
{
    for(int j =0; j<ySize; j++)
    {
        delete[] volume[i][j];
    }
    delete[] volume[i];
}
delete[] volume;
```

Answer (score 1):

In reverse.

You need the same loop structure, but for every `new[]`, you need a `delete[]` instead, and now nested stuff must occur *before* outer stuff.

So:

```
int **x = new int*[M];
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    x[i] = new int[N];
}
```

becomes:

```
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    delete [] x[i];
}
delete [] x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy - Just do the steps in reverse
i.e. delete all those `volume[i][j]` that you have created
Then `volume[i]` for all `i` values
Then volume.

It is a bit like losing your keys - you just need to retrace your steps!

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is this: you need to have one matching `delete[]` for each and every `new[]`. You seen to have one instance of `new int**[]`, `xSize` instances of `new int*[]`, and `ySize` instances of `new int[]`.

So, you might free them all thus:

```
for(int i =0; i<xSize; i++)
{
    for(int j =0; j<ySize; j++)
    {
        delete[] volume[i][j];
    }
    delete volume[i];
}
delete[] volume;
```